# sugarCRM 6.5 still updated?

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm a little bit confused. I know that sugarCRM no longer supports version 6.5 as of 2016, but there are still security patches being applied in 2017 as per

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Resources/Security/sugarcrm-sa-2017-005/

Does this mean that no new functionalities will be added but security patches and bug fixes will still be applied?

**Support vs maintenance**

As per Clint's thread: https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/18434

> We are expecting to support and issue maintenance releases to v6.5
>   through summer 2015 when v6.5 hits it end-of-support period.

So I'm assuming that support for 6.5 ended in 2016, but on this page http://support.sugarcrm.com/Resources/Security/sugarcrm-sa-2017-005/ we see the mention:

> The list of affected products reflect all currently maintained
>   versions at the publication date of this advisory.

Which is a bit confusing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Sugar support. So it's no longer supported in any way shape or form it seems

> 6.5 is no longer supported and no additional patches of any kind (including security) are being developed. End of life for 6.5 was
>   reached in July 2017. Our current supported versions list can be found
>   here: http://support.sugarcrm.com/Resources/Supported_Versions/. This
>   blog post may also be helpful to read, especially if you're using CE:
>   Sugar Community Edition open source project ends.